# Android - Multi-Task?

Tags: java, android

I want to know if I can have the recognizer open while using other programs?
I'm looking for an example or tutorial on multi-tasking like this. Point and I will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this blog, it may help.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html

PS Where's Pip?

Comment: Ahh, he is the pet of Flinx, which you edited out of your post. It's from Alan Dean Foster books.

Comment: Many thanks Bill. Pip is good, we both appreciate your time. =]

Comment: Bill --- So, App Widget? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you DON'T open your own "SpeechRecognizer".  You request the OS to give you an handle to an instance *it* creates (and, quite possibly, shares with other active applications):

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html
>
> This service allows access to the speech recognizer. Do not
>   instantiate this class directly, instead, call
>   `createSpeechRecognizer(Context).`

The link goes on to say:

> This class's methods must be invoked only from the main application
>   thread.

The "UI thread" gets created automagically from your start activity.